# Make particular listview row background different color - Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating a listview from arrays compiled from data in my database. 
Array 1: firstnamearray (composed of first names)
Array 2: lastnamearray (composed of last names)

Each listview row will have a name listed in it. If the first name is "Joseph", for example, I would like the background of the row to be green. How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), firstnamearray, lastnamearray);

mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my CustomList Adapter:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] firstnamearray;
    private final String[] lastnamearray;

    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] firstnamearray, String[] lastnamearray) {
        super(context, R.layout.simplerow, firstnamearray);
        this.context = context;
        this.firstnamearray = firstnamearray;
        this.lastnamearray = lastnamearray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null, true);
        TextView firstname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        TextView lastname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lastname);

        cardnumber.setText(firstnamearray[position]);
        expdate.setText(lastnamearray[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I've researched this and seen some people talk about changing background color on click or selection, but I want it to have a different row color on creation (if first name "Joseph").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really simple just check if the name is **Joseph**. Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null, true);
    TextView firstname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    TextView lastname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    if(firstnamearray[position].equels("Joseph")){
    //setbackground color to your desired color
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));//color defined in xml
    }else{
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));// your default color
    }
    cardnumber.setText(firstnamearray[position]);

    expdate.setText(lastnamearray[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: will this work with scrolling? i read something about view positions changing with scrolling and people having problems in that the background color shifts to a different listview row

Comment: @user3794585 It didnot work when I was extending base adapter but you are extending array adapter so it might work. The fool proof way to make it work is adding an else clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you should work. can't believe i overlooked this